# Tabulators like in OpenOffice/LibreOffice

Tags: xetex, hebrew, tabbing, arabic

Is there any way to achieve the same result in LaTeX as done with tabulators in other Word Processors?

- The difference to tables is that the text is not limited to cells but can flow across there boarders.
- and I can define the tabulators per paragraph

It should also work with other languages (from right to left and left to right) like in this question: [Hebrew vs. German/English translation side-by-side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50631/hebrew-vs-german-english-translation-side-by-side)

[image: the first paragraph with tabulators]
[image: the second paragraph with tabulators]

Comment: meanwhile I have also fount the package `tabto` but it doesn't work with Hebrew either. Does anybody know a tabbing/tabto/tabulator environment for bi-directional text?

Comment: If you use `bidi` package in `xelatex`, then you can get perfect bidi tabular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `tabbing` environment; below there are some examples (the example is in Spanish, but that's not so relevant) of the use of this environment and a brief description of its main commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
Programa\quad \= : \= \TeX \\
Autor \> : \> Donald Knuth \\
Manuales \> : \\
\qquad\= The Advanced \TeX\ Book\quad\= David Salomon\quad\=
Springer-Verlag\kill \\
\>\textsf{T\a'itulo} \>\textsf{Autor} \>\textsf{Editorial}\\
\>The \TeX Book \>Donald Knuth \>Addison-Wesley\\
\>The Advanced \TeX\ Book \>David Salomon \>Springer-Verlag
\end{tabbing}

\begin{tabbing}
Fila 1 Columna 1\hspace{2cm}\= Fila 1 Columna 2 \\
\> Fila 2 Columna 2\hspace{1.8cm}\= Fila 2 Columna 3 \+\+ \\
Fila 3 Columna 3 \- \\
Fila 4 Columna 2 \> Fila 4 Columna 3 \\
\< Fila 5 Columna 1 \> Fila 5 Columna 2 \> Fila 5 Columna 3 \\
Fila 6 Columna 2 \> Fila 6 Columna 3 \- \\
Fila 7 Columna 1 \> Fila 7 Columna 2 \> Fila 7 Columna 3 \\
Fila 8 Columna 1 \' Derecha \\
Fila 9 Columna 1 \> y \' Fila 9 Columna 2 \\
\pushtabs
\quad\= Fila 10 Columna nueva 1\hspace{2.5cm}\= Fila 10
Columna nueva 2 \\
\> Fila 11 Columna nueva 2
\> Fila 11 Columna nueva 2 \\
\poptabs
Fila 12 Columna antig\"ua 1 \> Fila 12 Columna antig\"ua 2
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And now a brief description of the commands:

- `\=`  set tab.
- `\>` advance to next tab stop.
- `\<` used at the beginning of a line, it anhilates the effect of a `\+` for that particular line.
- `\+` Used at the end of a line, it causes all following lines to begin at the first tab stop; using  `\+\+` at the end of a line, following lines will begin at the second tab stop, etc.
- `\-`  Used at the end of a line, it anhilates the effect of a `\+`.
- `\'` causes the following text to be placed at the next tab stop; the preceding text will be written just before, with a separation controlled by the length `\tabbingsep`.
- `\\` end of line; newline.
- `\kill` ignore preceding text; use only for spacing.
- `\pushtabs` removes the current tabbing scheme (saving it before) allowing for a new tabbing scheme.
- `\poptabs` it reactivates a previously saved tabbing scheme.

Inside the `tabbing` environment, the commands `\=`, and `\'` are redefined; in this environment it is possible to get the accents by using `\a=`, and `\a'`, respectively.

I don't know if this will work with right-to-left languages.

Comment: thank you for this answer. But it doesn't solve my problem, because it doesn't work with right to left languages :-(

Comment: Just add `\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}` and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a modification of the user Gonzalo Medino's answer. To get bidi tabbing, just use `bidi` package and instead running `pdflatex` or `latex`, run `xelatex` on your document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
\setRTL % to typeset tabbing in RTL mode
\begin{tabbing}
Programa\quad \= : \= \TeX \\
Autor \> : \> Donald Knuth \\
Manuales \> : \\
\qquad\= The Advanced \TeX\ Book\quad\= David Salomon\quad\=
Springer-Verlag\kill \\
\>\textsf{T\a'itulo} \>\textsf{Autor} \>\textsf{Editorial}\\
\>The \TeX Book \>Donald Knuth \>Addison-Wesley\\
\>The Advanced \TeX\ Book \>David Salomon \>Springer-Verlag
\end{tabbing}

\begin{tabbing}
Fila 1 Columna 1\hspace{2cm}\= Fila 1 Columna 2 \\
\> Fila 2 Columna 2\hspace{1.8cm}\= Fila 2 Columna 3 \+\+ \\
Fila 3 Columna 3 \- \\
Fila 4 Columna 2 \> Fila 4 Columna 3 \\
\< Fila 5 Columna 1 \> Fila 5 Columna 2 \> Fila 5 Columna 3 \\
Fila 6 Columna 2 \> Fila 6 Columna 3 \- \\
Fila 7 Columna 1 \> Fila 7 Columna 2 \> Fila 7 Columna 3 \\
Fila 8 Columna 1 \' Derecha \\
Fila 9 Columna 1 \> y \' Fila 9 Columna 2 \\
\pushtabs
\quad\= Fila 10 Columna nueva 1\hspace{2.5cm}\= Fila 10
Columna nueva 2 \\
\> Fila 11 Columna nueva 2
\> Fila 11 Columna nueva 2 \\
\poptabs
Fila 12 Columna antig\"ua 1 \> Fila 12 Columna antig\"ua 2
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the output is perfect for RTL:

[image]

Even if you want to use `tabu` package, that package also work perfectly with `bidi` package. Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{bidi}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\setRTL % to typeset tabu environment in RTL mode
\taburulecolor |gray!50|{red}\arrayrulewidth=1pt
{
   \taburulecolor|yellow|{blue}\tabulinesep=1mm
      \begin{tabu}{|X|X|} \hline
      Here the lines & are drawn in blue        \\ \taburulecolor{green} \hline
      But starting from here & they are green coloured !                \\ \hline
      And now a nested \textsf{tabu} & \begin{tabu}{|X|} \firsthline\hline
                                guess what colour \\ \hline
                                is used for rules ?\\ \lasthline\hline
                              \end{tabu} \\ \hline
      \end{tabu}
}
\end{document}
```

and here is the perfect bidi tabu:

[image]

Comment: But aren't you only giving examples of "align beginning of text to this point" tabs?