# Tab stops and text direction; Latin and Hebrew/Arabic

Tags: tabbing, right-to-left, fancytabs

Is there a package available which offers the following functionality (or if not, does someone have an idea how to achieve this): I would like to use tab stops but also define the "side" of the tab stop where the text is put. To be more precise I was hoping to have something like:

- **Tab_Right:** Latin text starts at the tab stop and goes to the right; Hebrew or Arabic text starts somewhere to the right of the tab stop and ends at the tab stop
- **Tab_Left:** Latin text starts somewhere to the left of the tab stop and ends at the tab stop; Hebrew or Arabic text starts at the tab stop and goes to the left
- **Tab_Center:** Both Latin and Hebrew/Arabic text is centred at the tab stop

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, to get "align at start of text", "align at end of text" and "align center" you can use the [tabu](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55946/) for how this works in a bi-directional setting).

The package doesn't seem to support "align right" and "align left", but you can:

- Contact the author and ask him to add support for this.
- Defines two macros, say `\tabalignleft` and `\tabalignright`, which expand to `r` or `l` depending on whether you're in a right-to-left context or not. Note that this might be a little tricky, as you're going to be using them within the optional parameter of another macro. I'm not sure how exactly to define them, you can look at the [bidi](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bidi) sources for inspiration or ask Vafa Khaligi.