# Side-by-Side translations

Tags: vertical-alignment

So I'm trying to set up a kind of side-by side translation in LATEX and I have tried two minipages as well as two columns and it doesnt quite work the way I want it too. The final goal is something like Spark Notes NoFearShakespeare

Comment: Welcome! Package `paracol` is designed for that: do `texdoc paracol` to open the manual. There are other packages, too.

Comment: On CTAN, https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol?lang=en, the "Suggestions" lists related packages. Useful to see what is available.

Comment: Another package [parcolumns](http://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns) is your friend. Check out this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59415/31034

Comment: @Cicada paracol seems to be exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.